# Intel Optane and Dual Boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, optane

I have the following case:

I have a 128GB M.2 SSD where I want to install Ubuntu.
I have a 256GB SSD where I want to install Windows,
and  I have a 1TB HDD i want to use in Windows.

Now I was thinking for to accelerate Programs and everything to install an Optane SSD (32GB) for the HDD.

Will this cause any issues for my Dual Boot/Ubuntu System?

Thank you for advice in advance.

Best Regards!

Edit:

- Motherboard: [Z390 Aorus Pro](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/sp#sp) w/ two M.2 M-key slots for SATA or NVMe SSD
- CPU: i7-9700k
- HDD: WD Blue 7200RPM
- M.2 SSD: Samsung 850 EVO
- SSD 256GB: Samsung 840 EVO Basic
- Optane: Intel Optane M.2 2280 32 GB PCIe NVMe 3.0 x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the Optane M.2 module into M2M, the shorter of the M.2 sockets (see page 20 of your [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z390-aorus-pro_wifi_1001_190708_e.pdf)), it must be 'paired' in Windows with the GPT-formatted HDD using Intel's Rapid Storage Technology utility (pp. 46-47, op cit.)

Optane serves as a transparent cache for the contents of the HDD, but when you change something on the HDD, Linux won't be able to update the Optane for what's in the HDD, so even if the Linux ntfs-3g package can read from it (I have not tested this), writing to it is perilous.

Therefore, if you want to access a file in Linux, it must be on either one of the SSDs, or an externally connected device. [Intel specifies](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024018/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html):

```
Operating System  

Q: What operating systems does Intel® Optane™ memory support when used for system acceleration?*
A: Intel® Optane™ memory requires Windows 10 64-bit to be used as a system accelerator.

Q: Is Linux* supported when using Intel® Optane™ memory for system acceleration?
A: No, the accelerated SATA drive must be running Windows 10 64-bit.

Q: Can Intel® Optane™ memory boost the performance of multiple drives?  
A: No, Intel® Optane™ memory can accelerate one SATA-based drive.
```

There is some experimenting going on with Optane and Linux, such as [this post](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-optane-16gb&num=1).